# getting "memory_efficient_attention() got an unexpected keyword argument 'scale'" on hugging face using the inference API of diffusion model?

Tags: huggingface, stable-diffusion

[Hugging face Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ybYt.png)

i tried to enter different prompts and the same error keep showing up with different models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, "https://huggingface.co/prompthero/openjourney-v4", this seems now operative for me when earlier it was not.

...evidently the error has something to do with an issue related to an incompatible PyTorch version...